# What is the order of operations inside a return statement when having several methods?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, operator-precedence

In the following statement what would be the order of operations?

```
... return array.map(some funct).join().sort()
```

Is it from right to left or left to right?
Or depends on the type of function present in the statement, meaning that every case is unique. If so what is a good rule of thumb to display the methods: which comes first and after that and so on?

Thank you

Comment: [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: The `.` operator chain is evaluated left-to-right. It is definitely **not** the case (given that simple example) that anything depends on what functions are involved.

Comment: The last thing going to be evaluated is `.sort()` and that will throw an error btw, because strings (one returned from `join`) don't have a method called `sort`

Comment: I see... Thanks for clarify. I've been confused with this way too long...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property access operators have left-to-right associativity:

```
array.map(func).sort().join()
```

is the same as

```
(((array).map(func)).sort()).join()
```

It really wouldn't make sense the other way round, you couldn't even group it in a syntactically valid fashion.

Regarding the order of evaluation, that is *always* left-to-right in javascript. In the case of method calls, there is only one sensible order anyway: evaluate the object, then access the property and evaluate it to the function value, the call that function.

Answer (score 1):

From left to right is the default order in js.

Also, there are some js libraries that let you chain functions from right to left using helper functions.